# wrong encoding when using child_process spawn or exec under Windows

Tags: windows, node.js

Using the `dir` command in Windows CMD will result in the following output:

```
Verzeichnis von D:\workspace\filewalker

22.12.2013  17:27    <DIR>          .
22.12.2013  17:27    <DIR>          ..
22.12.2013  17:48               392 test.js
22.12.2013  17:23                 0 testöäüÄÖÜ.txt
22.12.2013  17:27    <DIR>          testÖÄÜöüäß
2 Datei(en),            392 Bytes
3 Verzeichnis(se), 273.731.170.304 Bytes frei
```

Using `exec` or `spawn` will result in this:

```
Verzeichnis von D:\workspace\filewalker

22.12.2013  17:27    <DIR>          .
22.12.2013  17:27    <DIR>          ..
22.12.2013  17:48               392 test.js
22.12.2013  17:23                 0 test������.txt
22.12.2013  17:27    <DIR>          test�������
2 Datei(en),            392 Bytes
3 Verzeichnis(se), 273.731.170.304 Bytes frei
```

Here is my Node Code:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
    child;

child = exec('dir',
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

Comment: I managed to fix it by adding `cmd /c chcp 65001>nul &&`(this command sets cmd's console output to utf-8) at start of my exec command, so your would look like `cmd /c chcp 65001>nul && dir`, it should work.

Comment: @BladeMight Thank you so much! You should make this into an answer, would've saved me some time ':D (and others too, seeing the number of upvotes on your comment)

Comment: @yaba Okay, I did it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to fix it by adding `cmd /c chcp 65001>nul &&`(this command sets cmd's console output to utf-8) at start of my exec command, so your would look like `cmd /c chcp 65001>nul && dir`, it should work.

If you write cross-platform can use `process.platform`, to determine when you need that, something like that:

```
var cmd = "";
if (process.platform === "win32") { 
  cmd += "cmd /c chcp 65001>nul && "; 
};
cmd += "dir";

child = exec(cmd, //...
```

- Even though `dir` command is not "cross-platform".

Comment: Note that this solution hardcodes the code to only work on Windows, so at the very least let's change this solution to something that only adds the `chcp` call only if `process.platform` is `win32`? A solution that hardcodes "this code guaranteed can't run on unix/linux/macos" is not super great =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans According to OP, he used `dir` command which is obviously Windows-only, so the solution is also Windows-only.

Comment: certainly, but people (like me) will find this question on google looking for a way to ensure the encoding takes on windows, without hurting unix/linux/macos, so slightly improving the answer with `process.platform` checking is absolutely worth during for future visitors to the site looking for answers. This is mostly a request to improve the answer so it's more universal, and benefits everyone, rather than just windows code.

Comment: but it doesn't make sense to write something like this: `var cmd = ""; if (process.platform === 'win32') { cmd += "cmd /c chcp 65001>nul && "; } cmd += "dir"; //...exec....`, it looks very strange to me... using a `Windows` command and *ensuring that you are using* **Windows** afterwards...? Though I understand your suggestion, so I updated the answer.

Comment: No it doesn't, but it does when you need Node to capture the execSync output of, say, `perl oldCLIutility.pl` rather than `dir` This will happily run on every OS, but on Windows very much needs the codepage set to utf8, or things start to go very wrong when it tries to write a non-ascii character to stdout (similar to dir reporting a filename with unicode characters in it).

Comment: Well, *that* makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it (Simplified Chinese) by below code, don't know the coding page for other languages, maybe you can find it from Microsoft website:

```
  const encoding          = 'cp936';
  const binaryEncoding    = 'binary';

  function iconvDecode(str = '') {
      return iconv.decode(Buffer.from(str, binaryEncoding), encoding);
  }

  const  { exec } = require('child_process');  
  exec('xxx', { encoding: 'binary' }, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        const result = iconvDecode(stdout);
        xxx
  });
```

Comment: ```const iconv = require("iconv-lite");```

Comment: This worked for me with cp866 encoding

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

> There is a second optional argument to specify several options. The default options are

```
{ encoding: 'utf8',
  timeout: 0,
  maxBuffer: 200*1024,
  killSignal: 'SIGTERM',
  cwd: null,
  env: null }
```

That is Node defaults to utf8, while Windows has different code pages for different language version.

Comment: However, the [Buffers and Character Encodings](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings) section suggests that there's no bultin encoding for programs that generate output in Windows ANSI codepages.