# GIT. Web interface (Node.js). Wrong encoding

Tags: node.js, git, encoding

I'm trying to build web interface for GIT on Node.js.
Currently I have one problem: wrong Unicode encoding while 'git commit'. Commit message are shown in gibberish in log. And I have no clue on which step in which way I need to correct.

At this point I have:

1) UTF-8 encoded HTML page for interface;

2) Node.js `child_process.spawn()` to execute git commands;

3) `["-C",repo.path,"commit","-m",post.msg]` as an argument list to pass to git;

When I execute the same command from git shell (Under Windows if it matters) - everything is fine.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

**Update**

I guess I won't have this question answered, but still add one detail:
it feels like somewhere message is converted from UTF8 to ISO 8859-1

**Update2**

Looks like 8859-1 - is my default CMD.exe (who proceed my commands) encoding... still have no idea on what to do with it.

Comment: `child_process.exec()`  has an `encoding` option - did you try it?

Comment: See similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731785/wrong-encoding-when-using-child-process-spawn-or-exec-under-windows

Comment: @IgalS. child_process.spawn does not have `encoding` option, because it returns stream instead of buffer. And this option only affects output information.

Comment: As far as I understand from documentation it affects both input and output and sounds like it can solve your issue. Can't you use the buffer instead of a stream?

Comment: Used it earlier, but was forced to use `spawn` because of huge amount of output data (which was cut in case of `exec`). Though I'll try `exec` when I have more time for only `git commit` processing (when no output needed at all), but I don't really think it will help, reason is in _Update2_ of my question.

Comment: @IgalS. Have not tried you suggestion yet, and found it useless then, because I need Unicode support also for `log` filter, where output cannot be trimmed. Though solution was found (at last).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of problem was not about git, cmd or node.js. It was my stupid mistake.
On client I wrapped data into `encodeURIComponent` before send. On server unwrapped it with `unescape`. It took too much time to notice it.
Now, after I replaced `unescape` by `decodeURIComponent`, it works perfectly well.